# Extract items to a variable and assign them to an array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm working in a project in PowerShell and I have a variable like that :

```
$aaa = "spo, viorel, ramy"
```

I'm trying to put every single word of my variable to an array as something like that :

```
$array = ["spo", "viorel", "ramy"]
```

Did someone know how can i doing that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$array=$aaa.Split(',')
```

Comment: yes like you say its
$array=$aaa.Split(', ')
Its work very nice
Thanks you !